# How do I sort redis hset with numeric keys

Tags: redis

I have a data structure that looks like the following

`data[price] = amount`

so if I entered this in redis as

`hset mydata 300 500`

I can increment the key like so

`hincrby mydata 300 500`

I am using the Python redis Package. From Python I can get the minimum keys by like so

`min(redis.hgetall(keyname))`

But this is an operation in order of O(N) and the official documentation cautions against using this in production.  The other approach I have considered is sorting the keys and getting the minimum value.  Something that looks like:

`redis.sort(keyName)[0] #pseudocode`

But I am not sure how to do this.  I'd appreciate any ideas to either sort numeric keys in hset or get minimum value of the keys

Comment: Did you try EVAL (Lua script)?

Comment: Thank you very much.  No, I haven't tried that.  I should mention that I am using Python redis package. I will update the question